# How to output to file depending on source calling class using log4j

Tags: java, spring, architecture

I have a common DAO class with the logger initialized by its name.

I have something like this:

```
public class QueueDaoImpl implements QueueDao {

private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(QueueDaoImpl.class);

@Autowired
private StoredProcedureFactory storedProcedureFactory;

@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true, value = "transactionManager")
public EnqueueRespVO enqueueMessage(EnqueueMsgReqVO req) throws DAOException {

    EnqueueRespVO toResponse;

    try {
        EnqueueMessageStoredProcedure sp = storedProcedureFactory.getEnqueueMessageSP();
        Map<String, String> inParams = BeanUtils.describe(req);

        Map<String, Object> out = sp.execute(inParams);

        toResponse = new EnqueueRespVO();

        toResponse.setErrCode((Integer) out.get(EnqueueMessageStoredProcedure.ERROR_CODE_OUT_PARAM));
        toResponse.setErrDescription((String) out.get(EnqueueMessageStoredProcedure.ERROR_DESC_OUT_PARAM));

    } catch (DataAccessException e) {
        final String msg = String.format("A database error has occurred. Error = ", e);
        //log.error("[login] - Ended with an error. ", msg);
        throw new DAOException(msg, e);
    } catch (IllegalStateException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException e) {
        final String msg = String.format("A internal error has occurred. Error = ", e);
        //log.error("[login] - Ended with an error. ", msg);
        throw new DAOException(msg, e);
    }

    return toResponse;
    }
}
```

Then, I have two classes (posted below), 'RetryCallUssdJob' and 'SendErrorDetail' that use 'QueryDaoImpl' as composed object to do the database logic.

(I'm using Spring to inject the Dao beans)

Example of *RetryCallUssdJob* class

```
@Component
public class RetryCallUssdJob {

    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RetryCallUssdJob.class);

    @Autowired
    private QueueDao queueDao;

    public synchronized void execute() {
        here i'm using the queueDao instance injected by the spring context
    }
}
```

Example of *SendErrorDetail* class

```
 public class SendErrorDetailHandlerImpl implements ISendErrorDetailHandler {

    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SendErrorDetailHandlerImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    private QueueDao queueDaoImpl;

    @Override
    public BaseRespVO execute(Map<String, Object> params) {
        here i'm using the queueDao instance injected by the spring context
    }
}
```

I would like to know how to make output of 'QueryDaoImpl' logger redirected to different log files depending on what calling class is?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is tricky, I'd do one of two things:

1) Pass in the Logger in on the method call
or
2) Have different marker interfaces for the DAO that have different loggers injected by spring.

1 is easier, 2 is more declarative.

Comment: Thanks Rob, Yes the first one is easy to implement but given the architecture mentioned, is it a good practice to do that?

Comment: Sure, there is no reason not to.  Most people don't pass loggers around because it's inconvenient, and Log4J makes it easy to get it from within the class, so there is no need to pass them down.  But, from a purist IOC standpoint, the logger should come from the outside world.